# Presentar el número de control con mayor asistencia de un grupo

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

```
select grupo,control,count(*) as asistencia
from asistencia
where grupo = '14'
group by control
having count(*)>=all(
select count(*) as asistencia
from asistencia
group by control);
```

Sí a esta consulta le quitamos *where grupo = '14'* nos muestra los números de control con mayor asistencia de todos los grupos, pero quiero que sea especificamente sea del grupo 14 y hasta ahora no me arroja nada
¿Cómo podría especificarle que solo busque los del grupo 14? Abjo están las relaciones[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente sea porque tengas más grupos que el 14. Prueba así:

```
select grupo,control,count(*) as asistencia
from asistencia
where grupo = '14'
group by control
having count(*)>=all(
select count(*) as asistencia
from asistencia
where grupo = '14'
group by control);
```

Si esta solución no te funciona, modifica tu pregunta añadiendo tu dataset en SQL para que podamos probar la consulta.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Ya quedó